# execute command mvn clean install failed when integrate with Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I try to build Jenkins with maven project and in goal I defined: clean install.
But it failed with the below reason:

[image]

I try to execute the command `mvn clean install` in command line but it works fine even with eclipse IDE. 
I also check the network and see I can connect successfully. 
Any solution in this case.

Comment: can you please share following information: 1. what command you used to execute the maven execution (meaning, you use clean shell execution in jenkins, or you used withMaven in combination with sh). 2. are you sure you are in the same folder where the pom.xml file is ? 3. please expand a bit more error log

Comment: are you under proxy????

Comment: @SVMadhavaReddy yes Reddy, iam under proxy. So what should i do in this case?

Comment: @BigGinDaHouse , 1 : before integrating with Jenkins system, my maven project is in Eclipse IDE, and at that time, i can run maven successfully using command : mvn clean install (using both on IDE or in commandline). then i try to integrate with Jenkins system. then in configuration of this maven project with Jenkin i specify the command to run is mvn clean install. 2. Sure, i specify the path of pom.xml file.  3. full log is below :

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.40.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect (DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)

Comment: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0 (Native Method)

Comment: Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.40.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.40.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect

Answer (score -1):

By default, Jenkins can't access the internet if you are under `Proxy`. So please configure proxy in jenkins. Here I am attaching [a link](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/214230/how-do-you-configure-jenkins-to-work-with-a-proxy-server) to configure the jenkins. Hope this helps. If anything comes up, please comment below.

Comment: Did you try configuring the proxy??? Your error is mostly because of the proxy config only. You can search in google if you want.